# Given cash flows, what is the interest rate of the following contract?

Tags: present-value

I am presented with an investment opportunity where I am given #481,000 on day 1. Thereafter, every 10 days, I am required to give back #50,000 every for 100 days (10 * 50000 = 500000).

How do I calculate the interest rate I am paying?

I am guessing I have to use the present value of annuity problem to find out the interest rate.

So, my present value is #481,000. My "annuity" is 50000 every 10 days. First payment is due on the 10th day. Last payment is due on day 100.

Plugging the above values in wolframalpha I get .7107% for interest rate. I divide that by 10 to get per day interest rate and multiply by 365 to get 25.94%

I am surprised to see the above answer. It is a lot more than 14% which is what the rate would be if I were to pay 500000 at the end of 100 days. Is my reasoning incorrect?

Comment: This question is too basic to be on-topic for this site dedicated to quant-finance professionals, so I have to close it. However, the answer provided is good and you should be careful the way you annualize your interest rate (use compounding).

Answer (score 1):

The annuity method is the correct method. I am not familiar with wolframalpha but I assume it is correct.

Look at it this way: in the second case (take out 481,000, repay 500,000 after 100 days) you have full use of the borrowed 481,000 for 100 days.

In the first case (takeout 481,000, repay with an annuity of 10 payments over 100 day) you effectively borrow less because they force you to start repaying some of it after just 10 days. In a rough sense you only borrow half as much over time (in term of dollar days) so it is not surprising that it is a much more costly loan. The amount you repay is the same (500,000) but the amount available to you is far less, resulting in (roughly) twice the cost.